# Android style a SeekBar

Tags: android, android-styles, android-seekbar

I want to create a style for my app's `Seekbar`s. I just want to change the color of the thumb and the bar itself.

I managed to change the thumb name like this:

```
<style name="MySeekBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar">
    <item name="android:thumbTint"> @color/turquoise </item>        
 </style>
```

but I'm not sure how to change the bar's color. I know how to do it with code, but not in the xml:

```
seekBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.turquoise), Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

How can I style the color filter with a style defined in xml?

Comment: add <item name="colorAccent">#ffff00</item>. this shoud work

Comment: coloraccent didnt work

Comment: try adding this to AppCompatSeekbar  android:theme="@style/MySeekBarTheme" . make sure its appcomapt one . it shoud work. let me know

Comment: but the parent of my theme as you can see is already parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
android:progressTint
```

to change the color of progressing part of the seek bar and

```
android:progressBackgroundTint
```

to change bar background's color in your style

Comment: exactly what i needed

Comment: Only from API 21

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `android:color` atributtes with the color you prefer.

**background.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line">

    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#D9D9D9"/>
    <corners android:radius="1dp" />

</shape>
```

**progress.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shape="line">

    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#2EA5DE"/>
    <corners android:radius="1dp" />

</shape>
```

**style.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/seekbar_background"/>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip android:drawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**OR USE ON YOUR SEEKBAR THEME AS FOLLOWING**

Since `SeekBar` uses `colorAccent` by default, you can create a new style with your custom color as `colorAccent` then use `theme` attribute to apply it to the SeekBar.

```
<SeekBar>
    .
    .
    android:theme="@style/MySeekBar"
    .
</SeekBar>
```

**in the @style:**

```
 <style name="MySeekBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar" >
        <item name="colorAccent">#ffff00</item>
 </style>
```

Comment: How do I apply it to my app's theme?

Comment: Please check my updated answer - updated for theme style